# How sign to GraphQL with Cypress

Tags: graphql, cypress, signing

I have such an endpoint
[image]

my code:

```
    it('Test POST Request', () => {
    cy.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://some.com/graphql',
        form: true,
        retryOnStatusCodeFailure: true,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: {
            query: "mutation signIn($email: String!, $password: String!) {\n  signIn(email: $email, password: $password) {\n    ... on AuthInfo {\n      token\n    }\n    ... on SignInFailure {\n      errorCode\n    }\n  }\n}",
            variables: {"email":"max","password":"Pass"}
        },
    }).then(res => {
        cy.log(res);
    })
})
```

but I receive an issue
[image]

I tried with const query, but result is the same

Comment: How about the `form: true` option? It converts the body values to url encoded content, but you should send a json, which you try to do later with the `Content-Type` header as well.

Comment: It's a server-side error. The error is clear. If you use express as a web server framework, you need to add `body-parser` middleware

Comment: @slideshowp2, what is body-parser middleware, could you please show an example?